# ionic: horizontally center align application on desktop

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

**Question:** Application should render in center of the screen when user view my ionic mobile application on the desktop browser.

**attempt 1** : I tried  using wrapper div on it with width fixed in my case `max-width:732px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` but ionic don't allow us to append div over app screen goes blank.

**attempt 2** : Used width for inner element like (header, footer, ionic-view ) and tried align that in center but header `.bar` class breaks header as it is positioned element with this fix also didn't work expected;

**attempt 3** : Used position and try to align with `width:calc(50% - 732px);` still header breaks;

**my understanding** : ionic-view `.scroll-content` is positioned element, it create new element for scroll so won't be fix with margin, text-align, wrapper or inner element

**expectation** : Is there any way to fix this issue? i want my application to look like this resolution independent in center of the screen: https://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/26a6dbbu/1/

Any help is much appreciated advance. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you are runing your application. Are you using "ionic serve" ?

Comment: i am using "ionic serve --liverhood"  but my question is different, i want user to see application in  center view when user is using desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can run your ionic application using:

- ionic serve  (normal desktop view)
- ionic serve --lab (This will show you the mobile views of your ionic application based on the platforms you set)